SDL window not closing in C
I have some simple SDL code:
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    const int WIDTH = 1280;
    const int HEIGHT = 800;
    SDL_Window *window;
    SDL_Renderer *renderer;

    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO | SDL_INIT_EVENTS) < 0) {
        printf("SDL initialization failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        return 1;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Chess Engine", SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED,
                              SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED, WIDTH, HEIGHT,
                              SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);
    if (!window) {
        printf("Window creation failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    if (!renderer) {
        printf("Renderer creation failed: %s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
        SDL_Quit();
        return 1;
    }

    bool window_should_close = false;
    while (!window_should_close) {
        SDL_Event event;
        if(SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0) {
            printf("Events are polling\n");
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                window_should_close = true;
            }

            if(event.type == SDL_KEYDOWN && event.key.keysym.sym == SDLK_ESCAPE) {
                window_should_close = true;
            }
        }

        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        // render

        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);
        SDL_Delay(100);
    }

    SDL_DestroyRenderer(renderer);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}


Everything runs, and the window appears. When I do something that polls the events, I get the printf in the loop running. My problem is that when I press ESC, or press mod+q (kill active window) on the SDL window, nothing happens. I have to close the terminal that I ran the program from for it to exit. I'm running hyprland on arch linux.

Change if(SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0) into while (SDL_PollEvent(&event) > 0) Otherwise, you only process one event per outer loop and [apparently] the keydown event gets squashed. There are mouse movement [and other] events and you may overflow a queue. With the change, things work fine.
